# Can I set the advertised port from the assigned port by scaling kafka using docker compose?

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I am trying to scale a kafka using docker compose.

my docker-compose.yaml looks something like this:-

```
version: '3'
services:
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=127.0.0.1
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT=9092
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=zookeeper
```

And the I try to scale it up using

```
$docker-compose scale kafka=3
```

The problem with this is the container ports needs to be unique, thus i changed the ports section to this:-

```
ports:
      - "9092-9095:9092"
```

however, now I have no way of knowing what port got assigned until runtime, is there a way to retrieve the ports assigned and assign it to the environment variable KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT?

I've seen quite a few examples around that defines 3 separate services for each kafka service, which i don't really like, as this breaks the DRY principle.

Answer (score 0):

You need to repeat yourself because you cannot edit the environment variables during a scale operation. If you're on a single machine, you cannot advertise `127.0.0.1` and the same port multiple times, as you've described.

If you are using Docker Swarm, then the brokers would be on separate hosts anyway, so the ports could then be the same, and that's where the scale operation is truly useful. Otherwise, you're making one machine do three times the work of one broker, for little gain

If you really don't want to "repeat yourself", that is where a Kubernetes Helm Chart would help to template out multiple, stateful services

---

Aside: that Zookeeper container doesn't use advertised names or any variables starting with KAFKA

And you should advertise the external host IP, not 127.0.0.1